# How to display multiple columns in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to display multiple columns in a UITableView.

For Example:

**TableView**

```
   FName        LName    Age

   -----        -----    ---

   Abby         Michale   34
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define a custom cell in IB, which will contain 3 labels and in function:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         static NSString *DetailCellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DetailCellIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *cellObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (UITableViewCell*) [cellObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        // setup your cell
     }
```

when you define the cell in IB give each label a tag, so when you need to put a text there you can retrieve it by tag like this:

```
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:NAME_TAG];
        label.text = myObject.name;
```

and repeat this with other 2 labels. The tag is a unique number.

Put this code instead //setup your cell comment

Comment: I have created a custom UIView subclass named as "DetailCell" and add three label on it .Add above written code on the tableview of 
Employee Detail UIView subclass.Run it ,it does not show any label on tabelView.

Comment: If you create it in IB you're supposed to create a UITableViewCell, not a UIView.See this link for creating customized cells in detail:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 24):

I think the correct way of doing this is UICollectionView. Started with UITableView and finally failed at some point due to unexpected behavior while trying to implement scrolling both left-right and up-down.

Please check this awesome post for a complete and up-to-date solution:
http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

Result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Much better than the multi-label hacks for sure

Answer (score 3):

I have created [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView). I believe your problem can be solved using the same technique.

You can learn the source code of [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView). The code is really short.

Comment: Default cell count - 4 columns x 9 rows.   Just compiled downloaded sample projekt to device, and it really lagged.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but we've open sourced our fully featured table component:

https://github.com/flexicious/iOSDataGrid

Some screenshots:

http://www.ioscomponents.com/Home/IOSDataGrid

Feel free to use!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `UIView` subclass containing, say, three `UILabel` elements as subviews. Then set the cell's `contentView` property to this custom view.

Answer (score 0):

add three labels as sub viewsinto uitableview cell's content.then assign apprrpriate values to it
eg:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


}

//frame should be set accordingly(means should be framed accordingly).

UILabel *l1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100,100)];

UILabel *l2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110,10,100,80)];
UILabel *l3=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,60,100,50)];

[cell.contentView addSubview:l1];
[cell.contentView addSubview:l2];
[cell.contentView addSubview:l3];
 return cell;
 }
```

Comment: this is not a good approche to do the required thing see the above answer that is the correct approche to do the things done