# How to get columns in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display multiple columns in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview)

I have an `UITableView` with 30 rows. I would like each row to have a date, a title and a name.
Right now it's like this:

```
Oct 29 name title
```

But the names and titles change so I have something like that :

```
Oct 29 name title
Oct 30 biggername biggertitle
Oct 30 xx title
```

I would like to make 3 equals columns like this:

```
Oct 29 | name | title
Oct 31 | b... | bi...
Oct 30 | xx   | title
```

How can I do that in my `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best and easy way to get this thing use `UITableViewCustomCell`.
See this link - [Custom tableView Cell](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/) 
In cell XIB take 3 `UILabel` for each row then use them as your columns.

If this is not suitable for you just search **Custom TableView cell on google** :)

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I 'link' the View.xib file to my CutsomCell.h file ?

Comment: delete that view.xib .. take a `UITableViewCell` and then add `UILabel` on this ... dont forget to set its class name what is your custom cell class name .....

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have managed to accomplish this was with a custom `UITableViewCell` that had a label for each column.  This way you can specify the width of the "columns" as the width of each label, then set their text in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

For `UITableViewCell` you can do this task by making 3 `UILabel` of same width and then add all of these `UILabel` in cell

```
[cell addSubview:yourLabel];
```

And if you want to add this separate image between then just make a `UIImageView` and then add this `UIImageView` as subView of cell.

```
[cell addSubview:yourImage];
```