# iphone: how make Multiple Columns in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, multiple-columns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display multiple columns in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview)

I have multiple rows and columns of data. But iPhone UITableView contains only single column and multiple rows. How do I display my multi column data following Apple's Human Interface Guidelines? Any ideas?

Comment: change your x for new column... :)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.ioscomponents.com/Home/IOSDataGrid

Comment: check this similar answer it may be better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview#29249737

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use GridView for your this requirement, see this bellow links for the Demos and Tutorial ...

1. [Grid-View-in-IPhone-using-UITableView-1665](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Grid-View-in-IPhone-using-UITableView-1665.php)
2. [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView#readme)
3. [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

I use this below code to display Time-Table  with multiple columns, Some code for Example ..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"gridCell";
    UITableViewCell *gridCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(gridCell == nil)
    {
        gridCell =  [[[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
        gridCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        gridCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSArray* items = [_grids objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    int imageIndex = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;

    while (imageIndex < items.count)
    {
        int yPos = 4 + yOffset * 74;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            CGRect  rect = CGRectMake((18 + i * 80), yPos, 40, 40);

            UIImageView* imageView = [self gridImageRect:rect forImage:[items objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
            [gridCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];

            rect = CGRectMake(((80 * i)-4), (yPos+44), 80, 12);

            UILabel* label = [self descriptionOfImage:imageIndex inRect:rect];
            [gridCell.contentView addSubview:label];
            [label release];

            ++imageIndex;

        }

        ++yOffset;
    }

    return gridCell;
}
```

I hope this help you...

Comment: @ani use first option from my answer this link http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Grid-View-in-IPhone-using-UITableView-1665.php here you can set the multiple column in tableview

Answer (score 2):

Either you can subclass your tableViewCell or you can use this [MDSpreadView](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView)