# How to create Tableview with multiple columns in a single row.

Tags: swift, tableview

How to create Tableview with multiple columns in a single row. Then how we are identifying which column and row is selected

Comment: you should use collection view inside tableview cell

Comment: Would you please provide some code that you tried or image that you want?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873167/iphone-how-make-multiple-columns-in-uitableview

Comment: I want to know whether its possible or not.

Comment: Eg: in a single row, there are 4 columns.How to find which column is user selected using table view

Comment: @Akash it is absolutely possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display multiple columns in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview)