# Table view with multiple columns in ios 4,5 and 6

Tags: uitableview, multiple-columns

I want to create a table view with multiple columns, I want to display each student mark for different subjects.

I googled it but I didn't find an exact solution of what I need. I did find some links which are broken. I want tableview like exact grid view i.e. columns separated by lines. Please give me some idea.

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  }
```

What to write in the above method? I want this as a subview of my main view controller.

I followed this link: [How to display multiple columns in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview)

but I am very new to Objective-c, so please guide me how to define custom cell in ib

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the tableview style like this...

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
```

There are different styles available ...

```
  UITableViewCellStyleDefault,  // Simple cell with text label and optional image view (behavior of UITableViewCell in iPhoneOS 2.x)
UITableViewCellStyleValue1,     // Left aligned label on left and right aligned label on right with blue text (Used in Settings)
UITableViewCellStyleValue2,     // Right aligned label on left with blue text and left aligned label on right (Used in Phone/Contacts)
UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    // Left aligned label on top and left aligned label on bottom with gray text (Used in iPod).
```

Hope this helps !

Cheers !

Comment: could u plz give me any link which  is useful to my rewquirement

Comment: you saved my day, I was going to do it using custom views inside cell,  didn't know it was so simple to add two labels. Thanks!