# Create multiple column table with search filter function

Tags: objective-c, json, tableview

1.I need to create a multiple column table in my view controller to display json data.I was studying tutorial in youtube, but those table view tutorial only have single column.

2.Here is my single column table view code.

```
#import "inventoryVC.h"
@interface inventoryVC () <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *inventoryarray;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSArray *searchresult;
@end

@implementation inventoryVC

@synthesize tableview = tableview;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.inventoryarray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"first item" , @"second item", @"third item", @"fourth item", @"fifth item", @"sixth item", @"seventh item" ,nil];
self.searchresult =[[NSArray alloc]init];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma table View methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [self.searchresult count];
}
else {
    return [self.inventoryarray count];
}

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CellID";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchresult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.inventoryarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;

}

#pragma search methods

-(void) filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

self.searchresult = [self.inventoryarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString  {

[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]] ;

 return YES;
}
```

3.I created an array called inventoryarray to hold a dummy data to display in the table view. Is that possible i put json data in the array ?

Comment: I suggest you run a search for '[ios] [UITableView] multiple columns' before you get negative votes.

Comment: You would have to create a custom uitableviewcell for each row and set up labels and buttons in that custom cell.  check out this question / answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855857/how-to-display-multiple-columns-in-a-uitableview

Comment: After I create the custom cell in my table view, is that all I need to do is tell xcode that which json data is to display at which label ? @yan

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do this would be creating a custom UITableViewCell and divide setup the labels and column separators in there.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll try it out.

Comment: By the way, how to add a column separators ? I actually still hasn't get the concept of it.